# Bxslider пропускает слайды

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. На странице имеется 2 идентичных слайдера с картинками, которые показываются по 4 штуки. Слайдеры сделаны с помощью bxslider. Они работают, но с одним нюансом: каждый раз когда перематываешь дальше, слайдер пропускает по одному слайду. То есть, в одном слайдере 9 картинок и они идут в слайдере так: 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9. В другом слайдере идентичная ситуация. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и как ее решить? Спасибо.

Конфигурационный скрипт для слайдеров:

```
$('.bxslider').each(function (i, slider) {
      sliders[i] = $(slider).bxSlider({
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 4,
        slideWidth: 195,
        slideMargin: 30
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй инициализировать каждый слайдер отдельно общими параметрами, а не через each. Повесь на коллбеки (onSlideNext, onSlideAfter) вывод индекса и прочего в консоль и напиши результат (http://bxslider.com/options)